# Generalization of the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I was looking for a generalization of the $\textit{Residue theorem}$ in the case where I consider a complex number elevated to a generic phase of the identity.

Let's do an example. Let's assume that I would like to compute

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mid z \mid =1}\frac{dz}{z}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{t}{z})(1-tz)} 
\end{equation}
where $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mid t \mid < 1$, then the only pole inside the unit circle is located at $z=t$ and applying the $\textit{Residue theorem}$ we get
\begin{equation}
2\pi i \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{1-t^2} = \frac{1}{1-t^2}
\end{equation}
Now I'd like to consider the family of integrals (for $n>3$)
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mid z \mid =1}\frac{dz}{z}\frac{1}{(1-tz^{\omega_n})(1-tz)} 
\end{equation}
where $\omega_n = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does it exist a generalization of the $\textit{Residue theorem}$ that allow to evaluate the above integral ? Or more general, does it make sense to try to evaluate the above integral ?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you can just rearrange the fraction in the integral so that you can clearly see the poles? ie multiply top and bottom by $z^{-\omega_n}$

Comment: Isn't the pole at $z=t$ *on* the unit circle, not inside it?  The integrand isn't continuous on the path of integration.  Did you mean to $|t|<1$ perhaps?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant $\mid t \mid < 1$

Comment: For $\omega \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $z^\omega$ isn't meromorphic at $z=0$ so **no the residue theorem doesn't apply** to $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mid z \mid =1}\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{(1-tz^{\omega})(1-tz)} 
dz$. Please take a look at a proof of the residue theorem as a direct consequence of the Cauchy integral theorem.

Comment: I see many thanks, but then if the $\textrm{Residue theorem}$ does not apply, does is still make sense to try to evaluate the above integral ? Is there a way to do it ? Many thanks

Comment: In order to define $z^{\omega}$ for non-integral $\omega$, you need to use $\log z$; that exists as a continuous (and then analytic) function only on a cut of the plane - usually along a ray from the origin - so, you need to split the integral at the point where the cut intersects the disk and use the corresponding branch on each side, so the integral is not on a closed curve anymore and you need to make a choice - the usual choice of the cut alongside the negative reals splits the integral at $z = -1$, or $\theta = \pi$ and you can write an integral that way, but it may not be easy to compute